# Can I keep training a decision tree in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, decision-tree

Does my training set have to be two big variables to train my decision tree or can I use a for loop to keep adding training data? I ask because I have a lot of data.

Comment: What function are you planning on using? If you're using a pre-built one, then you probably can't do it in a loop. If you're implementing your own, then you probably can.

Comment: I was going to use the pre-built classification tree class. Hmm, That puts a dampener on things.